# Finding your own contribution

Tags: support, android-app, display-names

Is it possible to search your own name. I commented on a post regarding really big prime numbers. I offered a math library I wrote for currency handling.  Because his user I'd was something like @user333...  that's all I typed but there was more digits in place of that ellipsis

I'm still learning my way round the android app and taking a reputation beating for lack of knowledge.

I use a phone, laptop isn't too well at the moment.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve. You can also use the mobile version of SE web sites if the app lacks any functionality you need.

Comment: @DeerHunter didn't know mobile site existed. Igot here via ask ubuntu, the first thing it say was you on mobile get the app

Comment: You find your comment under `activities` on your profile page.

Answer (score 1):

**In the app:**

If you want to search for a different account by name, use the hamburger menu to go to the site, then tap the site name and tap "Users", then type the user name you are looking for in the search box.

If you want to look at your own activity to find it, tap the hamburger menu and select your name at the top to view your profile. You can then scroll down and look for your activity.

I find the mobile site to be a bit more functional, especially the user profile page.

**On the mobile site:**

If you want to search for a different account by name, you can search for it by tapping the "Users" tab at the top, then tapping the magnifying glass and typing the user name in the search box.

If you want to look at your own activity to find it, you can see your activity by visiting your profile. Tap the SE icon at the top left, then tap your user name. Tap "Activity", then scroll down to where it says "summary". There is a pink drop down on the right and you can select different activity types from there (e.g. "Comments") and look for whatever you are searching for.